# update with inner join raising a syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables

[image]

and I want to update table **Contacts**, so that the field **companyId** will be **newCompanyId** in **table2**.

I've tried the following query:

```
UPDATE contacts
SET contacts.companyId = table2.newComapnyId
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN table2 
ON contacts.contactId = table2.conatctId
```

But I get a syntax error. I've searched, and as far as I could find this is how I'm supposed to write the query.

*(Please forgive the typos, in the real query I double checked and there are no misspellings of names and such...)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some RDMS you don't have to specify the FROM-clause as it's already included in the statement. Try this:

```
UPDATE contacts c
INNER JOIN table2 t
ON c.contactId = t.conatctId
SET c.companyId = t.newComapnyId
```

Comment: The `SET` line must be the last line, then it should work.

Comment: @Andre Thx for pointing out missed out on that when posted the answer

Comment: @andre, your comment together with the marcus H's answer did the trick. You should make an answer out of it.

Comment: Really most dbms? It's not ANSI SQL anyway.

Answer (score -1):

For SQL SERVER

Use Alias

```
UPDATE c
SET c.companyId = t.newComapnyId
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN table2 t
ON c.contactId = t.conatctId
```